# Q: HttpDelete for MVC controller using KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, controller

```
    [HttpDelete]
    public ActionResult DeleteCustomer(int id)
    {
        var cus = customerContext.Customers.Find();
        customerContext.Customers.Remove(cus);
        customerContext.SaveChanges();
        return null;
    }
```

Above is my controller code for delete click event. Below is my js file. Call ajax to do delete action. But when I click delete button, it always pop-up a "Not Found" dialog. I have no idea what happened in the front end or back end. So sad. Need help, please. Thank you.

```
    self.deleteCustomer = function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "DELETE",
        url: "../Customer/DeleteCustomer/",
        data: { id: self.cusId() },
        success: function (result) {
            alert("Deleted!");
            GetCustomers();
            $('#AddCustomer').modal('hide');
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error.statusText);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For what you have posted it seems like you are using a path instead of a "url" in the url property. Try to use `url: "/Customer/DeleteCustomer",` instead of `url: "../Customer/DeleteCustomer/",`. If it still doesn´t work open chrome development tools and sniff the network to see where (url) it is sending the request.

To check if your roting is correct (in backend), you can install Postman (chrome plugin) and send a DELETE request and verify if the controller receives the request.

Regards.

Comment: I don't think the URL does matter. Because I tried. Still, display Not Found dialog. But still, thank you.

Comment: Have you checked if the request is being sent to the correct url with correct http method (through develpment tools, F12 - Chrome and IE in Windows)? What about sending a DELETE request through Postman?

Comment: Hi, dime2lo. I checked the console. The error message is "jquery-1.10.2.js:8720 DELETE http://localhost:49360/Customer/DeleteCustomer/ 404 (Not Found)  jquery-1.10.2.js:8720"

Comment: Is this routing correct? It is not missing "api" before Customer or something? Try to use Postman to send a delete request and verify if it hit the controller. Or, if you prefer, just to debug (verify the request is hitting the controller), change the annotation from `[HttpDelete]` to `[HttpGet]` and try to access the url localhost:49360/Customer/DeleteCustomer from the browser. If you hit the action the route is OK. Don´t forget to get back to `[HttpDelete]` after that.